# Why does the logout did not occur properly from Facebook app?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website and I want to make users able to log in with their Facebook accounts to my website the problem that I faced was when they login they get their profile page and when they logout they go to the index page but if they refresh the page they found that they logged in again (because the Facebook account is still not logged out) when they logged out from Facebook separately and refresh again it shows that the log out from the website succeeded .
This is my logout function :

```
<?php  
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) 
{   
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'xxxxxxx',
      'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'cookie' => true,
       ));

       //ovewrites the cookie   
    $facebook->destroySession();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: ./');
}      
?>
```

Is their something missing should I add any code to log the users from facebook other than this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after a lot of work and test I found that there is two missing parts in the code above in order to work I should make it as following:

```
<?php  
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) 
{   
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
      'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'cookie' => true,
       ));
    //access token is important for logging out from facebook DO NOT REMOVE IT
     $params = array( 'next' => 'http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/','access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken() );
    $logoutlink = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); // $params is optional.
       //ovewrites the cookie   
    $facebook->destroySession();

    session_destroy();
    header('Location: '.$logoutlink);
}

?>
```

first thing to add was `getLogoutUrl` to get the right logout URl which will log you out.

second thing was `'access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken()`  yes this parameter was a headache because i did not find any documentation that telling you should use it for logging out from facebook also; so without it I was logged out from the app but still logged in facebook (which make me login again automatically once I refresh the page) but with this parameter I was logged out from both of them. I hope this could help some body

Answer (score 0):

Just unset `$_SESSION['logged_in']`

Comment: but I use `session_destroy()` I think it does the same